# how do I position the remove button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve what is in this picture below but it is not working for me.

I tried to use position of relative and right to be 0px but nothing changed.

if I use top to be -2px it moves upwards but positioning it to the right is not working

[image]

```css
.remove {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  top: -1em;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div className="form-group mb-2">
  <label htmlFor="" className="mb-2">Contact Info <span>*</span></label>
  <div className="contact-info">
    <div className="info-items">
      <button className="remove">x</button>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label htmlFor="" className="mb-2">Phone Number <span>*</span></label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label htmlFor="" className="mb-2">Address <span>*</span></label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please correct the bootstrap libraries and CSS to what you are using (from CDN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.contact-info {
  position: relative;
}

.remove {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `className` attribute to `class`, so minimal example works.

`className` is for React. `class` is for normal HTML.

I also changed the `position` to `absolute` : (position relative is **relative** to its original position. position **absolute** is to absolutely position it), `top` attribute to `0px`,  so it is exactly in line.

Seems to work good.

```css
.remove {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group mb-2">
  <label htmlFor="" className="mb-2">Contact Info <span>*</span></label>
  <div class="contact-info">
    <div class="info-items">
      <button class="remove">x</button>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label htmlFor="" className="mb-2">Phone Number <span>*</span>
                                         </label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label htmlFor="" className="mb-2">Address <span>*</span>     
                                         </label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```